# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' for number game

Tags: python, string

I am a newbie at Python and i need help. I don't understand what to do no matter what this code won't work. I am trying to make a hotter colder number game.

```py
import math
import random
answer = str(random.randint(1, 1000))
guess = input('take a guess\n') # \n ---> newline  ---> It causes a line break
if abs(guess - answer) <= 250:
  print("You're warm!")
elif abs(guess - answer) <= 100:
  print("You're getting warmer.")
elif abs(guess - answer) >= 250:
  print("You're cold."
else:
  print("You're freezing.")
```

I've tried everything I know please help.

Comment: No, you didn't try everything. You should try to calculate with numbers (`int`) and not with strings. So instead of converting a number to a string, as you did in `answer = str(random.randint(1, 1000))`, you should convert the guess to a number instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` gets a `str`, which is a string of characters.

Before start comparing you need to transform `input` to something math can understand, in this case to a number. Depending on your needs you'll require more or less precision. In this case should be fine using an integer (`int`).

This process is called `cast` and to do so in python you can do `int(guess)` after asking for input.

Same for `answer`: you need an `int` (which `randint` already gives), because you must compare same types. You can't subtract apples from a bunch of bananas.